# Applying RE module on a Series

Tags: python

I have trouble applying the following to my series.

```
Data['Notes']
0       2018-06-07 09:38:14Z -- legal -- As per ...
1       2018-06-05 12:48:26Z -- name -- Holdin...
2       2018-06-05 17:15:48Z -- filing -- Answe...
3       2018-06-11 08:34:53Z -- name -- lvm i...
4       2018-05-11 08:31:26Z -- filed -- summo...
5       2018-06-01 16:07:11Z -- Name Rogers -- sent ...

import re

keywords = {'file', 'filing', 'legal'}
max_words_after  = 5

key_re = re.compile(fr"""
(?:{'|'.join([w for w in keywords])})   #keyword options group
\s((?:[\s]?[A-Za-z\']+[\s]?)    #capture word. include with line-breaks
{{1,{max_words_after}}})                #1 to max_words_after
""", re.VERBOSE|re.IGNORECASE
)

data['Result'] = pd.Series
def word_search(series):
     return key_re.findall(series)
data['Result'] = data.apply(word_search(data['Notes']))

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-e6b6bcbe720d> in <module>()
 13 def word_search(series):
 14     return key_re.findall(series)
  ---> 15 data['Result'] = data.apply(word_search(data['Notes']))
 16 
 17 

<ipython-input-32-e6b6bcbe720d> in word_search(series)
 12 data['Result'] = pd.Series
 13 def word_search(series):
 ---> 14     return key_re.findall(series)
 15 data['Result'] = data.apply(word_search(data['Notes']))
 16 
  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please tell me how I can get a result for every index position and append it to a new series within the data frame.

Comment: You have bad indentation for your `word_search` function. Please correct that so we can be sure just what you meant. Also show the full traceback for the error message. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Finally, is that the result of a session at the console? It is not completely clear what is input and what is output. If it is a console session, copy-and-paste the prompts as well. If it is code in a module, remove the output and show that separately.

Comment: Is this what you meant? I apologize I am very new.